# How to store JSON.parse result in parent object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am totally stumped and have tried everything on this... Trying to make a dynamically-created periodic table of elements.  I am pretty new to javascript and VERY new to using JSON data.  I have solved a lot of problems via StackOverflow but can't seem to find the answer to this problem.

I am trying to store the result of a JSON.parse statement as a parent class object but it just never seems to work...  Loading the JSON data via JSON.parse works fine but trying to access the data in a different parent method doesn't work.

```
var Parent_Object  = function() {
     this.parent = this;
     this.element_data;

     this.initElementData = function() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', '<data_location>', true);

        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                parent.element_data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);  // trying to store the result as a parent class object (or whatever it would be called)...
                document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML = "Status: JSON data successfully loaded...";
                document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML += parent.element_data[0].element_name;  // this works fine, no problem with this!
            } else {
                document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML = "Status: Couldn't find the JSON data...<br>";
            }

        };

        request.onerror = function() {
            document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML = "Connection error of some sort...<br>";
        };

        request.send();
    };

    this.laterFunction = function() {
        document.getElementById('json_status').innerHTML = parent.element_data[0].element_name;  // This doesn't work, data is gone!
    };

}
```

Here is small snippet of the JSON (warning, some of these values are still incorrect to be fixed later):

```
[
    {
            "element_name" : "Helium" ,
            "atomic_number" : 2,
            "id" : "el_2",
            "symbol" : "He",
            "period" : 1,
            "group" : 18, 
            "mass_upper_iupac" : 4.003,
            "mass_lower_iupac" : 4.003,
            "elemental_state" : "Gas",
            "category1" : "Non-metal",
            "category2" : "Noble gas",
            "category3" : "S-Block",
            "category4" : "Main group",
            "electronegativity" : 0,
            "ionization_energy" : 0,
            "electron_affinity" : 0,
            "common_charges" : [
                {
                    "charge" : 0
                }
            ],
            "isotope_abundance" : [
                {
                    "mass_number" : 3,
                    "abundance" : 0.00000134 
                },
                {
                    "mass_number" : 4,
                    "abundance" : 0.99999866 
                }
            ]        
    },
    {
            "element_name" : "Hydrogen" ,
            "atomic_number" : 1,
            "id" : "el_1",
            "symbol" : "H",
            "period" : 1,
            "group" : 1, 
            "mass_upper_iupac" : 1.008,
            "mass_lower_iupac" : 1.007,
            "elemental_state" : "Gas",
            "category1" : "Non-metal",
            "category2" : "Alkali metal",
            "category3" : "S-Block",
            "category4" : "Main group",
            "electronegativity" : 2,
            "ionization_energy" : 2.18e-18,
            "electron_affinity" : 72.8,
            "common_charges" : [
                {
                    "charge" : 1
                },
                {
                    "charge" : -1
                }
            ],
            "isotope_abundance" : [
                {
                    "mass_number" : 1,
                    "abundance" : 0.999885 
                },
                {
                    "mass_number" : 2,
                    "abundance" : 0.000115 
                }
            ]        
    }
]
```

Here's the HTML if it helps...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Periodic Table Test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="periodic_table_1"></div>
        <script src="periodic_table.js"></script>
        <div id="json_status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out callbacks, they're super useful in situations like this. Here's the fix for your example, but you should check them out more, they'll for sure help you grow as a JavaScript developer.

```
 var Parent_Object  = function() {
     parent = this;
     this.element_data;

     this.initElementData = function() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', '<data_location>', true);

        request.onload = function() {
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                parent.element_data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);  // trying to store the result as a parent class object (or whatever it would be called)...
                document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML = "Status: JSON data successfully loaded...";
                document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML += parent.element_data[0].element_name;  // this works fine, no problem with this!
            } else {
                document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML = "Status: Couldn't find the JSON data...<br>";
            }

        };

        request.onerror = function() {
            document.getElementById("json_status").innerHTML = "Connection error of some sort...<br>";
        };

        request.send();
    };

    this.getElementData = function (callback) {
        if (parent.element_data !== undefined) {
            callback(parent.element_data);
        } else {
            var refreshElementsInterval = setInterval(function () {
                if (parent.element_data !== undefined) {
                    callback(parent.element_data)
                    clearInterval(refreshElementsInterval);
                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    this.laterFunction = function() {
        // this is assuming you've already populated the element_data variable in the object. If you haven't it'll keep refreshing, and update your Id when you do.
        parent.getElementData(function (data) {
            document.getElementById('json_status').innerHTML = data[0].element_name;
        });
    };

}
```

---

P.S. I changed the first line of your Parent_Object function to `parent = this;` instead of `this.parent = this;` since I assume that's what you meant.

Comment: I tried what you suggested for hours to no avail until I noticed a small typo in your statement.. if (parent.elements_data !== undefined) {  should have been if (parent.element_data !== undefined) { But that fixed it, thanks a million!

Comment: @Cakes ops, sorry man! Well glad it worked eventually haha. Just edited the answer